# Conditional Expectations, Variances: Stuck on a practice exercise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $$ be a random variable with PDF (). Let $ = ^2$ be another random variable.
The following should be given in terms of the PDF $()$:

- $[|]$.
- $[|]$.
- $(|)$.
- $(|)$.
- The conditional CDF of $Z$ given $Y$.

$E[Y|Z] = E[Z^2|Z] = Z^2$, but i'm not sure how to follow on the remaining questions.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4084512/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$var(Y|Z)=0$, since $Y$ is defined by $Z$.

Given $Y$, $Z$ has two possible values.
$E(Z|Y)=\sqrt{Y}\frac{f(\sqrt{Y})-f(-\sqrt{Y})}{f(\sqrt{Y})+f(-\sqrt{Y})})$

To get $var(Z|Y)$, get second moment $E(Z^2|Y)=Y$  therefore $var(Z|Y)=Y(1-(\frac{f(\sqrt{Y})-f(-\sqrt{Y})}{f(\sqrt{Y})+(f(-\sqrt{Y})})^2)$

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate a bit more on how you derived the formula for the expectation $E[Z|Y]$ ?

Comment: To get$E(Z|Y)$. Note that $Z$ has two possible values $\sqrt{Y}$ with prob. $f(\sqrt{Y})$ and $-\sqrt{Y}$ with prob. $f(-\sqrt{Y})$.  Use definition of expectation to get the formula. The division be the prob. sum is necessary normalization.